# Cordova 11 Android doesn't get/ send cookie from api server

Tags: android, cordova, cookies

I am trying to pass server sent cookie on api call but cordova Android doesn't receive those cookies & doesn't allow me to set cookie myself. IOS works fine

i tried some 3rd party plugin, server has SameSite Lax ..cant change to None

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.